# handleRedirectCallback of @azure/msal-angular package is not getting called when using hashlocationstrategy in angular 8

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular8, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

**Objective -** I am implementing azureAD authentication using **@azure/msal-angular** and **msal** library in angular 8.

**Problem -** Everything works fine when using pathlocationstrategy but when using hashlocationstrategy the @azure/msal-angular library's callback is not getting called.

**Code Flow -**
User clicks on login button in HomeComponent -> user gets redirected to microsoft's login page -> user enters credential -> On successful login user is redirected to <strike>msalLandingComponent</strike> homecomponent (which is rendered in appcomponent's routeroutlet) where the callback (this._msalService.handleRedirectCallback) should execute.

**Code**

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/',
  redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/#/msal-landing'  
};
```

*also tried redirectUrl as http://localhost:4200/*

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
```

<strike>{ path: 'msal-landing', component: MsalLandingComponent }</strike>

```
];
```

HomeComponent - User clicks on login button which calls the onButtonClick()

**home.component.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Login" (click)="onButtonClick()" />
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _msalService: MsalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._msalService.handleRedirectCallback((error,tokenInfo) => {
      
    });
  }  

 onButtonClick()
  {
      this._msalService.loginRedirect();
  }

}
```

MsalLandingComponent - User is redirected to this component on successful login

**msal-landing.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-msal-landing',
  templateUrl: './msal-landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./msal-landing.component.css']
})
export class MsalLandingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _msalService: MsalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._msalService.handleRedirectCallback((error,tokenInfo) => {
      
    });
  }  

}
```

**Problem Description**

For redirecting user to microsoft's login page

```
onButtonClick()
  {
      this._msalService.loginRedirect();
  }
```

is called and after login user is redirected to the redirect url where in ngOnInit below code should execute

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._msalService.handleRedirectCallback((error,tokenInfo) => {
      
    });
  }
```

But this callback is not getting called when using hashlocationstrategy.

**Additional Information**
I think it is not possible to set the redirectUrl with a # in azure during app Registration.

So instead of setting the redirect url as "http://localhost:4200/#/msal-landing" we set it to "http://localhost:4200/". Such that the home component is called.

I have updated the above code by moving the ngOnInIt of msal-landing.component.ts to home.component.ts and deleted the MsalLandingComponent.

But in this case also the handleRedirectCallback doesn't get called. It gets called only when this code is put in the ngOnInIt() of app.compnent.ts. **Unable to understand why it is getting called in the root component which is the appComponent but not in the homeComponent.**